# What is the difference between set vs map in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I am still confused by the differences between the map and set datastructures in STL. I know set is storing the values in a sorted way, what about map? Does it store the values in sorted order?
Map stores pairs of values (key,value), what is the advantage of this feature?

Comment: Semantically, set and map are totally different data structures. You should go through a good tutorial to study when to use which.

Comment: They are both associative containers, are they not? By default, they use `std::less` as a comparator, and they follow strict ordering.

Comment: You can kind of think of a set as a hash where only the key is used and the value not utilized.

Comment: In the context of STL it is better not to thing that set is a hash. unordered_set is implemented with hash, set is *not*.

Answer (score 39):

At least for the ordered versions (`std::map` and `std::set`), a `map` facilitates use-cases of a `set` by allowing you to introduce an external key (`map::key_type`) to determine ordering of the elements that otherwise can't be derived from `map`'s data type (`map::mapped_type`). If the ordering can be wholly derived (by comparing 2 elements) from `map::mapped_type`, then you're typically better off using a `set`, in which case you'll avoid duplicating the key as `map::key_type`.

In a way, `std::map` is redundant and you can always use `std::set` instead by introducing a new element type which aggregates keys with data while providing the necessary comparison function. However, this is cumbersome and typically inelegant.

To clarify why a `set` may be cumbersome over a `map`; A `set` will store the `<key, data>` pair as an element while `map` will maintain a separation between the 2. This means, for instance, that for a `find` operation on a `set` where `find`'s parameter is constructed on-the-spot, an entire `<key, data>` element will have to be constructed while it's really on the `key` that's needed for the `find` operation. The construction of the `data` members of a `set`'s element is then redundant, and can be rather inefficient if, for instance, `data` members represent disk storage or involve some other complex or else time consuming construction operation. `map` alleviates this by only having to construct the actual `key` required for `find`.

To summarize, consider an element `<key, data>` for which you're wondering whether to use a `map` or a `set` to store multiple ordered elements. If `key` spans the entire `data` (meaning `data` is empty or else `key == data`) then you're better off using a `set` in which case you'll avoid a) duplicating `key` storage and b) likely having to keep 2 `key`s synchronized. If `key` is not contained in `data` then (you have to) use a `map`. The tricky part is when `key` is a (proper) subset of `data`. You then have to trade-off the cost of maintaining duplicate `key`s (for a `map`) vs the cost of constructing  `data` that doesn't overlap with `key` (for a `set`), the latter which may occur for `find` operations.

Comment: A major point is that the elements in a Set cannot be changed once they're placed in the set [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/]  If you're storing a collection of simple data items in an ordered way, then a set can work.  If you're storing structs ordered by one data member, and you want to be able to change the other data in the struct, take the ordering data member out to be a key and use a map.

Comment: You can if you make the other data members mutable.

Answer (score 21):

Conceptually, a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) is a collection of things, whereas a map is a mapping of keys to values.

Answer (score 13):

A [`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) stores keys sorted. It maps keys to values. Usually it is implemented as a binary search tree ([red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree))  for keys. A [`set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is a map where values are irrelevant.
[`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) (new in C++11) store keys unsorted and use hash table for search.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` and `std::set` are extremely similar. They both have a sorted collection of unique keys. Additionally, `map` has a value associated with each key.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is an associative container storing pairs of key-values with unique keys. `std::set` is also an associative container that stores a sorter set of objects (or keys).

You should have a look at [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: In which way the map storing the values? based upon the key? If it is stores based upon the key, is key sorted?

Comment: sets aren't really associative -- the contents of the set don't "associate" to anything else.

Comment: the elements in a map are always sorted by its key following a specific strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object

Comment: Guys, i understand it. In Map also, data gets sorted by keys.i got it from link "keys are sorted by using the comparison function".

Comment: @seand `sets` are considered "associative containers" in the C++ standard. It may be counter-intuitive, and could be derived from the fact that the implementation is similar to that of a map, except that only keys are stored. But that is the terminology we are stuck with now.