# std::unordered_set::find - construct an instance only for find()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

A lot of times I see my `key` is actually inside my `value`.
For example:

```
struct Elem {
    int key;
    // ... Other variables ...
}
```

That makes me want to use [std::unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) instead of `std::unordered_map`, because I already have the `key` stored inside my `value` - no need to waste more place for `std::unordered_map`'s `.first` (`key`).

Then I start implementing with `std::unordered_set` and get to the place I need to perform a `find()` over my `std::unordered_set`.
Then I realize I need to create an *empty-shell* `Elem` so I would be able to `find()`, beacuse `std::unordered_set::find` gets a `Key` for input

```
template < class Key,                    // unordered_set::key_type/value_type
       class Hash = hash<Key>,           // unordered_set::hasher
       class Pred = equal_to<Key>,       // unordered_set::key_equal
       class Alloc = allocator<Key>      // unordered_set::allocator_type
       > class unordered_set;
```

Sometimes building an *empty-shell* `Elem` is hard / wasteful / maybe even not possible?

For example, when my key/value is

- An iterator
- A reference
- A class with specific `c'tor` (not constructing the instance only with the `key`)

**Q. Am I missing something?**
**Q. Is there a way to do `find()` that isn't wasteful? I mean that doesn't make me create an instance I didn't want to**

- Something really strange to me - **that I already should have the element I'm looking for in order to find it**, or at least an *empty-shell* of it.

Comment: I emphasized the questions

Comment: Your title is _"std::unordered_set vs std::unordered_map trade-offs
"_, yet you are basically asking why `std::unordered_set` can't be used like an `std::unordered_map`

Comment: it's not that strange to me, a `set` contains unique *values*, it has no concept of *key*.

Comment: If you have access to C++14 and can switch to `std::set` instead, then you have an overload of [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) that accepts any type. You would also need to implement a custom comparator though.

Comment: @PasserBy - sorry about the title - I couldn't think of any other suitable name.

Comment: @appleapple - huh? Of course it does - how do you search for an element? + I didn't talk about unique values - I have the same problem in `std::multiset` as well.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis - actually I need `std::unordered_set`. Do you happened to know why it doesn't exist for `std::unordered_set` and only for `std::set` ?
From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find - sounds like exactly what I was looking for!  
`3,4) Finds an element with key that compares equivalent to the value x. This overload only participates in overload resolution if the qualified-id Compare::is_transparent is valid and denotes a type. It allows calling this function without constructing an instance of Key`.

Comment: @hudac well, maybe I should say it has no concept of *values*? `find` check certain *key* exist, not something comparable to it. (even worse, `cmp(key,key)` and `cmp(key,else)` can have different order)

Comment: @appleapple - maybe I don't understand it correctly. But as I see it - `std::set / std::unordered_set` are `STL`s for elements who hold their key - so it's a `key/value` combined. That's why you need to implement (if not exists by default) a `hasher` and an `equal_to` function.

Comment: @hudac a `std::*set<T>` is closer to what a `std::*map<T, void>` would be if it were well-formed, than to a `std::*map<T, U>` for any other U (where `*` is either ``, `unordered_`, `multi` or `unordered_multi`)

Comment: @hudac `hash` is for hash, it doesn't have the meaning of *extract the key of this object* by default. nor it need to have same result on two different type, [see this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J6jlqfz3fU1c8vtE)

Answer (score 0):

When choosing a data structure to hold your data you need to consider your use case.

If you want to look up data from a key you should use a `map`. If you just want to store unique values in a collection and you don't need to look them up use `set`.

I don't see why its so much trouble to insert a element as `map.emplace_back(elem.key, elem)` vs `set.emplace_back(elem)` if it means that down the road you can just query the elem as `map.at(key)` or `map[key]` vs having create an empty `elem`.

Besides, `std::set` does the whole key thingamajig (roughly) underwater anyway. (source: [What is the difference between set vs map in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088607/what-is-the-difference-between-set-vs-map-in-c))

Comment: "If you just want to store unique values in a collection and you don't need to look them up use" - I don't agree - in `std::set` you **do** have a `find()` method.  
"I don't see why its so much trouble to insert a element" - I'm talking about `find()`, not `insert()`.  
"Besides, std::set does the whole key thingamajig (roughly) underwater anyway." - I don't care what it do under the hood.